# how can i make a check constraint for table "B", in PostgreSQL, that checks if the value in table "A" is at least 1 or more?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, constraints

how can i make a check constraint for table "B" (desired_amount), in PostgreSQL, that checks if the value in table "A" (available_amount) is at least 1 or more?

Table B:

```
 CREATE TABLE public.cart_tb
    (
        cart_id integer NOT NULL,
        inventory_id integer NOT NULL,
        desired_amount integer NOT NULL,
        row_status integer NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT "cart_PK" PRIMARY KEY (cart_id, inventory_id),
        CONSTRAINT "cart_UK" UNIQUE (cart_id),
        CONSTRAINT "cart_inventory_FK" FOREIGN KEY (inventory_id)
            REFERENCES public."Inventory_tb" (inventory_id) MATCH SIMPLE
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
    )
    
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
    
    ALTER TABLE public.cart_tb
        OWNER to postgres;
```

Table A:

```
CREATE TABLE public."Inventory_tb"
(
    inventory_id integer NOT NULL,
    inventory_name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    brand character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    inventory_category character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    color character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    date_added timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    inventory_size character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    list_price money NOT NULL,
    sku character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    available_amount integer NOT NULL,
    row_status integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "inventory_PK" PRIMARY KEY (inventory_id)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public."Inventory_tb"
    OWNER to postgres;
```

This is for a school project, a POS system. im pretty new to databases and SQL in general.

Comment: Generally you'd use a trigger for more complex logic like "take the product ID from this inserting cart row and look it up in the inventory then check that the quantity going into the cart can be fulfilled from available stock" like this, or (if you're of the "triggers are bad" school of thought) you'd build it into another part of the app like the front end system or procedure that is loading the cart

Comment: The cart table definition has a major issue. The unique constraint on *cart_id* means you can **only have 1 item in the cart**. The PK having both *cart_id* and *inventory_id* suggest a missing table CART and this is actually a CART_ITEM table and is a resolution table between CART and INVENTORY.  Additionally it seems the requirement that *available_amount* has at least 1 item is a little short. Seems it should be at least the *desired_amount* column. Checking for just 1 means if inventory has 1 item when the customer desires 3 is a perfectly good order. The customer may disagree.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to this kind of problem:

1. Use a trigger that throws an error if the condition is not fulfilled. The downside of that is that there is always a race condition unless you use the (more expensive) `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level.
2. Denormalize the data model by duplicating the column from A in table B. Triggers on A make sure that the values are always the same. Then you have a simple `CHECK` constraint on B. The downside here is the data duplication.

Both approaches will incur a performance overhead on account of the triggers. Therefore, it is advantageous to choose the solution that has the triggers on the table that gets modified less often. If you have high concurrency, choose the second variant to avoid the race condition.